# How to make all image extensions accepted?

Tags: php, image

My brother made this code fo a site we're building but we don't know how to set it to where all picture file extensions are accepted. Can someone please help us out, it may be something so simple. Forgive me for being clueless.

```
   if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {
       $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blob` WHERE `id`='$id'");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
       {
            $imageData = $row["image"];
       }
       header("content-type: image/jpeg ");
       echo $imageData;
   }
   else {
        echo "error!";

   }
?>
```

Comment: What else is in `$row`?  Image type maybe?

Comment: This script retrieves the image and displays it on a webpage. Right now its only calibrated to accept jpeg images and gifs are severely damaged when shown.